# ListView.builder is not scrolling inside column

Tags: flutter, dart

I have `ListView.builder` inside scrollable `Column`. But The content inside `ListView.builder` is not scrolling.

```
final List<String> entries = <String>[
  'Item 1',
  'Item 2',
  'Item 3',
  'Item 4',
  'Item 5',
  'Item 6',
  'Item 7',
  'Item 8',
  'Item 9',
  'Item 10',
  'Item 11',
  'Item 12',
  'Item 13',
  'Item 14',
  'Item 15',
  'Item 16',
  'Item 17',
  'Item 18',
  'Item 19',
  'Item 20',
];
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return SingleChildScrollView(
    child: Column(
      children: [
        Text(
          'Heading',
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
        ),
        ListView.builder(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
          itemCount: entries.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return Container(
              height: 150,
              width: 150,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                border: Border.all(width: 2.0, color: Colors.red),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
              ),
              child: Center(child: Text('${entries[index]}')),
            );
          },
        ),
        Text(
          'Footer',
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: Try ListView inside ListView, remove Column and SingleChildScrollView. Add physics: ScrollPhysics(), to inner ListView.

Comment: Could you please explain the behavior? Do you have a header, a couple of items, and a footer, which all should act as one scrollable list? or do you need to keep the header fixed, scroll the list view items, and when it's finished scroll the column up to show the footer? because I think Custom Scroll View is a cleaner and better solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add this to your ListView.builder()

```
physics: const ScrollPhysics(),
```

Answer (score 4):

Add this line of code

`physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),`

Comment: Just the line I was missing.. Perfect ! Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to suggest a different approach. The `ListView` is entirely unnecessary. You can just loop over the entries inside the column directly. This will also respect the width of 150 that you indicated in the Container, which it doesn't do in the ListView

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return SingleChildScrollView(
    child: Column(
      children: [
        Text(
          'Heading',
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
        ),
        for (String entry in entries) Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Container(
            height: 150,
            width: 150,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              border: Border.all(width: 2.0, color: Colors.red),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
            ),
            child: Center(child: Text(entry)),
          ),
        ),
        Text(
          'Footer',
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add a scroll direction to your `ListView.builder()`

```
ListView.builder(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical, <- This is what you need
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
          itemCount: entries.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return Container(
              height: 150,
              width: 150,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                border: Border.all(width: 2.0, color: Colors.red),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
              ),
              child: Center(child: Text('${entries[index]}')),
            );
          },
        ),
```

More informations [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/listview-builder-in-flutter/)

Comment: I have already tried that, its not working.

Comment: Oh yea i just see that nothing is applied to your SingleChildScrollView(), you can add physics: ScrollPhysics() to your SingleChildScrollView()

Comment: you could also apply physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics() to it so your ListView.builder() knows to scroll. Which approach fits to your case?

Answer (score 0):

this is working for me

```
Column(
mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max, //Add this 
line onyour column
children:[
    SomeWidget(),
    Expanded(child:ListView.builder())
  ]
)
```